# Software to calculate forces between magnets

Tags: electromagnetism, software

I am working on a complex configuration of magnets and every time I make an experiment something unforseen happens. Now I believe I could speed up the development by sitting down and calculating the configuration in all scenarios. My question is however: Is there any software that can help me to calculate the forces between magnets. I am already working with AutoDesk as my CAD software.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are interested in the force on a complex configuration of magnets, you most likely will need a 3D electromagnetics FEM solver, something like Ansoft Maxwell 3D, Opera 3D, or other comparable software packages.